# Using merge with lettable operators

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an array of items that I'm mapping to observables that I need to combine using `merge`. I'm trying to do this using lettable operators. For example:

```
// obs is an array of observables
from(obs).pipe(merge());
```

However if I subscribe to this, it just emits an array of observables immediately rather than emitting the merged observable values.

I have tried:

```
from(obs).pipe(mergeMap(ob => ob));
```

This actually works as expected, but I would expect `.merge` to do the same thing. Is there a way I can flatten the observable using `merge`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator I wanted to use was `mergeAll` rather than `merge`.

```
from(obs).pipe(mergeAll());
```

The `.merge` operator takes the emission of an observable and chains the emission of the observable argument to it. In my original question, no transformation was being done at all and this was equivalent to just `from(obs)`.

You could also do `obs[0].pipe(merge(obs[1]))` if you had two Observables (or continue to chain them). `mergeAll` allows you to do this for an arbitrary number of input observables. The static `merge` operator also takes any number of input observables.